# how to stack multiple images side by side so it overflows its <div> boundary

Tags: html, css

I ran into a difficulty, where I used float or inline-block to stack images side by side, but on reaching the max-width of the div tag, it automatically stacks below.
Of course with overflow-x: hidden; I want to stack as many images as possible in a single line so I can animate it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        div {max-width: 250px;}
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="" width="100px"/>
            <img src="" width="100px"/>
            <img src="" width="100px"/>
            <img src="" width="100px"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this...

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        div {width: 250px;overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;}
  div img{display:inline;}
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.familyfriendpoems.com/images/hero/nature-nature.jpg" width="100px"/>
            <img src="http://www.familyfriendpoems.com/images/hero/nature-nature.jpg" width="100px"/>
            <img src="http://www.familyfriendpoems.com/images/hero/nature-nature.jpg" width="100px"/>
            <img src="http://www.familyfriendpoems.com/images/hero/nature-nature.jpg" width="100px"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works if you place your images in a table with one row.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {max-width: 150px; overflow-x: hidden;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table cellspacing=0>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src=""/> </td>
                        <td><img src=""/> </td>
                        <td><img src=""/> </td>
                        <td><img src=""/> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```